# Borrow checker complains about multiple borrowing, when only one will ever occur

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

Consider the following code (also [available on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=73caac3325c94626b547bca254a47304))

```rust
pub trait TextStream {
    fn next_str(&mut self) -> Option<&str>;
}

pub struct FilterTextStream<T: TextStream> {
    inner: T,
    maxlen: usize,
}

impl<T: TextStream> TextStream for FilterTextStream<T> {
    fn next_str(&mut self) -> Option<&str> {
        match self.inner.next_str() {
            None => None,
            Some(txt) if txt.len() <= self.maxlen => {
                Some(txt) // <-- this does not compile
                //Some(unsafe {&*(txt as *const str)}) // <-- this fixes the problem
            }
            _ => self.next_str()
        }
    }
}
```

The `TextStream` trait works like an iterator, except that the `&str`'s it yields do not have overlapping lifetimes. `FilterTextStream` works like a (specialized) filter iterator.

However, this code fails to compile, with the following error:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:18:18
   |
11 |     fn next_str(&mut self) -> Option<&str> {
   |                 - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
12 |         match self.inner.next_str() {
   |               ---------- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
15 |                 Some(txt)
   |                 --------- returning this value requires that `self.inner` is borrowed for `'1`
...
18 |             _ => self.next_str()
   |                  ^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
```

What surprises me is that I don't see how this is borrowing `self` twice. Either we return in line 15, or we return in line 18, so only one of the two will ever happen. My assumption is that this is nor a *real* problem, but one of these cases were the borrow-checker is not smart enough. Am I missing something?

Assuming I am right, I managed to circumvent this error using an `unsafe` block (see the commented-out line 16) by artificially "breaking" the lifetime dependency. Can anyone see a better way (i.e. without any `unsafe` block) to make this code compile?

Comment: I believe this is a [known issue](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2094-nll.html#problem-case-3-conditional-control-flow-across-functions) with the current implementation of the borrow checker. Unfortunately, I don't know the right workaround for this case.

Comment: @kmdreko thanks for your comment. However, as far as I know, this RFC has been merged in the stable Rust with version [1.36](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2019/07/04/Rust-1.36.0.html). So the problem described in your link is probably solved now. But granted, it is similar to the problem I have...

Comment: @Pierre-Antoine I submitted bug report https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/84361

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [The Polonius Talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_agDeiWek8w) rustc currently treats lifetimes in function signatures as if they are live for the entirety of the function body. So, if I understand currectly, it doesn't matter to rustc that the borrows are on different match arms.

The code type-checks with `cargo +nightly rustc -- -Zpolonius` which means that when Polonius features are fully integrated the code should type-check without any changes.

I couldn't find a better workaround than using `unsafe` like in the example in question and adding a comment saying the `unsafe` can be removed at some point.