# How to access mutable iterables inside a nested loop

Tags: rust, iterator, borrow-checker, mutability

Every now and then, I run into the same issue with borrowing (or not borrowing) mutable variables inside a loop, and I finally sat down and compiled a minimal example. As a result, the code is a little silly, but it is the shortest version that I could come up with that highlights the problem:

```rust
struct Association {
    used: bool,
    key: usize,
    value: String,
}

impl Association {
    fn new(key: usize, value: &str) -> Self {
        Association{used: false, key: key, value: value.to_string()}
    }
}

fn find_unused<'a>(data: &'a mut Vec<Association>) -> Option<&'a String> {
    for k in 0.. {
        for a in data {
            if a.key == k && !a.used {
                a.used = true;
                return Some(&a.value);
            }
        }
    }
    None
}

fn main() {
    let mut assoc = vec![
        Association::new(7, "Hello"),
        Association::new(9, "World")
    ];

    println!("{}", find_unused(&mut assoc).unwrap());
    println!("{}", find_unused(&mut assoc).unwrap());
}
```

This will fail with an error because `data` was moved before. If I borrow it instead, it will fail because it was borrowed before. I would like to **understand exactly what is happening and how to solve it in general**. In particular, I do not want to change the structure of the code, even if it is silly. I do not want to implement a workaround, because this is just a minimal example: Please assume that the nesting of the loops is the "right" way to do it, even if it is utterly silly here, which it definitely is.

I would only like to know how to communicate to the borrow checker that what is happening here is actually ok. I know of *one* way to do this:

```rust
fn find_unused<'a>(data: &'a mut Vec<Association>) -> Option<&'a String> {
    for k in 0.. {
        for j in 0..data.len() {
            if data[j].key == k && !data[j].used {
                data[j].used = true;
                return Some(&data[j].value);
            }
        }
    }
    None
}
```

This compiles without error and works as intended. In my naïve understanding, there should be a way to express the above with iterators instead of indexing, and I would like to know how that would be done.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Returning a reference from a HashMap or Vec causes a borrow to last beyond the scope it's in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38023871/returning-a-reference-from-a-hashmap-or-vec-causes-a-borrow-to-last-beyond-the-s)

Comment: better code https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ed80fad42894aceafc592b8f5713278c

Comment: Dear @Stargateur, please note my disclaimer and assume that code restructuring is not the solution, even if it _absolutely_ works for the _minimal_ example. Understand that this is not _actually_ the code I am writing, and restructuring in this fashion will not always be feasible. I did play around with non-lexical lifetime support enabled on the nightly channel, but at least I can't make it work with that feature enabled either.

Comment: you are already using NLL, read twice the answer of shepmaster, it's a current limitation of the current NLL implementation. Try `-Zpolonius`. On the solution I give it was just to help you there is a way using iterator, you can't complain if you didn't create a [mcve] that really show your use case. I'm not a magician.

Comment: @JeskoHüttenhain I'm not sure enough to post an answer, but I had a similar situation recently and stumbled across: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/51526 which matched my code well enough.  Seems like conditionally returning a borrow from a loop is specifically the issue, it doesn't know to end the loop's borrow. (And I would guess the indexing version works since data is not held borrowed.) But, ultimately I don't know NLL enough to say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you want is possible if you:

- make fresh mutable borrows in each nested loop
- And wait for `rustc` to integrate more Polonius capabilities. (Can experiment now with `cargo +nightly rustc -- -Z polonius`). While you wait, you could use `unsafe` like in this post: [Borrow checker complains about multiple borrowing, when only one will ever occur](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67165025/2482570)

Keeping the rest of your code the same and focussing on this part, but with the `return` commented out:

```rs
fn find_unused<'a>(data: &'a mut Vec<Association>) -> Option<&'a String> {
    for k in 0.. {
        for a in data { // Error - but rustc says what to do here
            if a.key == k && !a.used {
                a.used = true;
                // return Some(&a.value);
            }
        }
    }
    None
}
```

The error messages from rustc say what to do and why. The mutable borrow in the parameters is moved (used up) by the call to `into_iter()` in `for a in data`.

`rustc` recommends a mutable re-borrow. This way we don't try to borrow something that has already been moved. Making that change (and keeping the `return` commented-out for now), the following now type-checks:

```rs
fn find_unused<'a>(data: &'a mut Vec<Association>) -> Option<&'a String> {
    for k in 0.. {
        for a in &mut *data { // we took rustc's suggestion
            if a.key == k && !a.used {
                a.used = true;
                // return Some(&a.value);
            }
        }
    }
    None
}
```

If we un-comment the `return`, we get an error saying that the lifetime of the value we're returning doesn't match `'a`.

But if we run with `cargo +nightly rustc -- -Z polonius`, the code type-checks.

> @stargateur suggested trying polonius in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70228392/how-to-access-mutable-iterables-inside-a-nested-loop#comment124145066_70228392)

Here's my guess as to why Polonius helps:

- For the current rustc borrow-checker, lifetimes in function signatures are treated in a relatively coarse and simplistic way within the body of the function. I think what's happening here is that `'a` is supposed to span the entire function body, but the fresh mutable borrow for `a` only spans part of the function body, so Rust doesn't unify them.
- Polonius tracks origins of borrows in types. So it knows that the lifetime of `&a.value` comes from `a`, which comes from `data`, which has lifetime `'a`, so Polonius knows the `return` is OK.

I'm basing this on [The Polonius Talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_agDeiWek8w) but [The Book](https://rust-lang.github.io/polonius/what_is_polonius.html) is probably more up-to-date